# Break out of nested for loop without stopping outer loop

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
let items = ["A", "B", "C"];
let desc = ["a 1", "b 2", "c 3"];
let args = "1 b 2 3";
let query = args.split(" ");
let i2;
let i;
console.log("Search query: " + args);
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < query.length; i2++) {
         if (items[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1 || desc[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1) console.log(items[i]); return;
    }
};
```

I would like to stop the child `for` when the if evaluates to `true`, but i don't know how to do it.

Current output: `A`
Desired output: `A B C`
Output using `break`: `A B B C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break out of a loop you use the [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) keyword

> The break statement terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

```js
let items = ["A", "B", "C"];
let desc = ["a 1", "b 2", "c 3"];
let args = "1 b 2 3";
let query = args.split(" ");

console.log("Search query: " + args);

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < query.length; i2++) {

    if (
      items[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1
      || desc[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1
    ) {
      console.log(items[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this, but you have other issues in your code.

```js
let items = ["A", "B", "C"];
let desc = ["a 1", "b 2", "c 3"];
let args = "1 b 2 3";
let query = args.split(" ");
let i2;
let i;
for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
  var breakChildLoop = false;
  for (i2 = 0; i2 < query.length || !breakChildLoop; i2++) {
    if (items[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1 || desc[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query[i2].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      breakChildLoop = true;
      console.log(items[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I think you mean `i2 < query.length && !breakChildLoop`

Comment: Why not use `break`??

Comment: @m0meni - i didnt said not to use, i gave another option.

Comment: @SO - you should really implement a rule that someone that answers on the same question will not be able to downvote other answers.

Comment: @Dementic it’s a bad answer. I normally upvote the other answers if they’re good. You should never do what is in your answer, and I consider it bad practice.

Comment: @m0meni unless you can provide proof that this is bad practice (reason for it to be so), then its your PERSONAL opinion and nothing more.